# how to put multiple strings into a single string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
```

when ever I copy and paste the above code, I need to remove space between them i.e., ('/n' tag between them) by doing validations........ and it shouls look like this

```
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span><span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'</span><span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
```

How can I get it.....Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is javascript/jquery? It seems to be an edit problem

Comment: Are you saying you have a `<textarea>` element that might have such values pasted into it, and that you want to then remove the newline characters from within that `<textarea>`? (If not your question makes no sense - if you're talking about editing your source code then just use your code editor's find/replace function if there are too many to remove manually.)

Comment: Please tell us what the context is.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use jQuery for that, you can to that by native `replace` method:

```
var myStr = "..."; //whatever string you have
myStr = myStr.replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
```

---

but I am not sure if this is really solves your problem, it looks like you trying to do something different, anyway the above code will remove all "carriage return" and "new line" characters from the string